# How can we debug in VS code for python command line app (maybe launched from VS code terminal) on remote linux server connected through SSH?

Tags: python, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, ssh

I can connect to the remote linux server from VS code through SSH by using the Remote-SSH extension.
I can run linux commands from VS code terminal.
I also have the python debugger extension in VS code.
But I do not understand how do we debug python code. When we start debugging we get below options

1. Python file
2. Module
3. Remote Attach
4. Attach using process Id

For a linux command from my python repo can I connect using Process Id? Is it possible to debug this way?